# Under What Conditions Is $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ Where M Is the Set of 2x2 Matrices a Function and Not a Function?

Tags: matrices, functions, proof-verification

I came across a problem that I thought was interesting. I attempted to solve the problem below, and I would be grateful if someone would check my logic in what follows.

*Let the set M of all 2 by 2 matrices be defined as*

$$M =  \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 
            a & b \\ c & d 
       \end{bmatrix}\Bigg| 
            \thinspace 
            a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z} 
       \right\}$$

*Let $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and suppose $m\in M$.  $\thinspace$Then $f\big( \left[\begin{smallmatrix} a&b\\ c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right]\big)=ad+(bc)i$*.

*Under what conditions is the relation $f$ a function and when is it not a function?*

**My Solution**

*First, I maintain that the way that f is currently defined satisfies the definition of a

function, because it is everywhere defined and it is well-defined.*

**Proof**

*Existence: Suppose that $x=\left(\begin{smallmatrix} p&q\\ r&s\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ is a matrix such that $x\in M$ and let $y = pq+(rs)i$ such that $y\in \mathbb{C}$. Then $\left(x,f(y)\right) \in f$. Thus, the preimage $x$ is mapped to at least one image $y$ in the codomain.*

*Uniqueness: Suppose that $z\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $z = ab+(cd)i$ and assume $y=f(x)$ and $z=f(x)$. But then $y=z$, so the preimage $x$ is mapped to a unique image in $\mathbb{C}$.*

$\Box$

*On the other hand, if $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb{C^*}$, then $f$ is not a function, because it is not everywhere defined. If $x\in M$ is the zero matrix, then $f(x) = 0 \notin \mathbb{C^*}$. Therefore, $f$ is not a function.*

What does the community think? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it is a function, and you can prove that it is surjective but not injective.

Comment: Ah, yes, I can see that your statement is true. What do you think about the proof above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is essentially correct, but you can better formulate it.

The first part (existence) can be simply done noting that:

$\forall a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow ab+i(cd)=z \in \mathbb{C}$ since $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{R}$ and  complex numbers are defined as $\mathbb{C}=\{z: z=x+iy, x,y \in \mathbb{R}, i^2=-1\}$.

Your proof of the second part (uniqueness) is a bit confused in the exposition. It's better to start with both $z,y \in \mathbb{C}$ and to show that:

if $z=f(x) $ and $ y=f(x)$ than $z=y$.  This is done as in your statement . Formally:

If there are $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $z=ab+i (cd)$ and $y=ab+i(cd)$ than $ z=y$ by definition of identity in $\mathbb{C}$.